# CSS or jQuery to cut down on matching A HREF and IMG SRC?

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, href

I have a few web sites I manage, and for thumbnail pictures (which could include lightbox or fancybox), the lines are substantially:

```
<a href="http://www.site.com/images/this-would-be-the-picture-we-want-x-full-size.jpg"><img src="http://www.site.com/images/this-would-be-the-picture-we-want-x-full-size.jpg"" width=200></a>
```

While I do not have leeway on removing the absolute path (too many people reposting pages) or shortening the filename (there are a LOT of pictures), is there a way to use CSS or JQUERY to simply call a full size when clicked without having to list the full path TWICE (once in the A HREF and once in the IMG SRC)

Thanks!

Comment: Why does the length of the filename matter to you?

Comment: But if the image is already there in full size, why do you need a link as well? You do realise that the images are not actually resized when loaded with the `<img>`, right? They're only displayed in a smaller size, but they are full size.

Answer (score 1):

This would be easy to do with jQuery - for example...

```
$('img').click(function(){

    window.location.href = $(this).attr('src');

});
```

However, this simply mimics a link behaviour - You should look at how your lightbox code works, it may use the `<a>` link as a trigger which could get bypassed using the above.

If you want to do it the other way around (keeping only the link) I would maybe do something like this when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a').each(function(){

        $(this).append('<img src="'+$(this).attr('href')+'" width="200">');

    });

});
```

However this would address every `<a>` link on your page so you might want to use a class to trigger this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand how it works now, and if the `src` and `href` are always equal, then

```
$("img").click(function() {
    window.location.href = this.src;
)};
```